# Limits of radicals of polynomials

Tags: calculus, limits

Given a polynomial $$p(x)=(x+a_1)(x+a_2)...(x+a_n)$$
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} p(x)^{\frac{1}{n}}-x$$
This limit seems to equal to the average of the $a_n$’s.
How do I prove this? I think it’s an inductive proof but I just don’t know how.
It might involve l’hopital but I managed to prove quadratic and cubic without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

$$\begin{aligned}
\log\left(p(x)\right)^{1/n} &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\log(x+a_k)\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\log x + \log\left(1+\frac{a_k}{x}\right)\right)\\
&= \log x + \frac{1}{nx}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k + \frac{\epsilon(x)}{x^2}
\end{aligned}$$

where $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty } \epsilon(x) = 0$.

Taking the exponential you indeed get that the expected limit is equal to the mean of the $a_k$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\bar a$ be the average of the $a_i$, and $A=n\bar a$ be the sum. Note that $$\frac d{dx}(x+\bar a)^n=n(x+\bar a)^{n-1}.$$

Thus for any $\varepsilon>0$, we know that $$(x+\bar a+\varepsilon)^n= x^n+Ax^{n-1}+O(\varepsilon)x^{n-1},$$

and $$p(x)=x^n+Ax^{n-1}+O(x^{n-2}).$$

Thus for any $\varepsilon>0$, we can find $x$ sufficiently large such that

$$(x-\bar a+\varepsilon)^n>p(x)>(x+\bar a-\varepsilon)^n,$$

that is to say, $$\lim_{x\to\infty} p(x)^{\frac1n}-x=\bar a.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$P=\prod_{i=1}^n (x+a_i)\implies \log(P)=\sum_{i=1}^n \log(x+a_i)=n \log(x)+\sum_{i=1}^n \log\left(1+\frac{a_i}x\right)$$
$$\frac 1 n \log(P)=\log(x)+\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n \log\left(1+\frac{a_i}x\right)\sim \log(x)+\frac 1 n\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}x$$
$$P^{\frac 1n}=e^{\frac 1 n \log(P)}$$

Just continue.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $t=p(x) /x^n\to 1$ as $x\to\infty $ and we can rewrite the expression under limit as $$x\cdot\frac{t^{1/n}-1}{t-1}\cdot(t-1)$$ and the fraction in middle tends to $1/n$ so the desired limit equals the limit of $$\frac{x(t-1)}{n}=\frac{p(x)-x^n}{nx^{n-1}}$$ and this is clearly $$\frac{a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n}{n}$$